# In iOS 7, Presenting View From TableView Shows Previous view in background

Tags: uitableview, ios7

Yea, horrible title for the question, but didn't know how to phrase well.  In iOS 7, I occasionally run into an issue on TableViews.  Sometimes, when presenting a view, the previous view stays visible until the animation is completed.  I have some TableViews that don't do this, so I'm really at a loss for the distinction.

Comment: Some code, screen shoot any thing?

Comment: is this only on the simulator or do you also experience the same issue with the device as well?